# Euro symbol in pgfplot unit

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, units

I want to create a chart with the Euro symbol as unit. But if I write \euro into the unit tag of tikz (with pgfplots) i only get an "e".

Here is a basic example of my Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.units}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ylabel=\euro,
        y unit= \euro,
        ]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get the "€"-Symbol into the units tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for `x unit` and `y unit` are typeset in math mode. You'd get an “e” also from `$\euro$`, because `\euro` is a *text* command. Use `\mbox` around the symbol.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.units}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ylabel=\euro,
        y unit=\mbox{\euro},
        ]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `xlabel` and `ylabel` are *not* typeset in math mode (by default). Just try `ylabel=ABC`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yeah, right.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I tried serveral ways and everytime I got the symbol the was an error at another place.